# Can't create Anaconda environment with python=3.4

Tags: anaconda, conda, python-3.4

I'm trying to set up a Anaconda environment with Python=3.4.

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda create -n py34 version=3.4
```

I already include the conda-forge channel, but still get this error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - version=3.4

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

When i try it with:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda create -n py34 python=3.4 -c conda-forge
```

I get:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package vc conflicts for:
python=3.4 -> vc=10
Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.4 -> pip
Package vs2010_runtime conflicts for:
python=3.4 -> vs2010_runtime
```

I'm pretty new to Anaconda and Python and dont know what to search for anymore.

This post: [Why conda cannot create environment with python=3.4 installed in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56850972/why-conda-cannot-create-environment-with-python-3-4-installed-in-it) didnt help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, 3 days later i found out that the latest Version of Anaconda is kinda broken. I downgraded to version 4.6.14 and now everythings seems to work.

```
conda config --set allow_conda_downgrades true
conda install conda=4.6.14
```

[Solving environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source. UnsatisfiableError:](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9004)

Answer (score 6):

Firstly you can provide more details by increasing the verbosity of the `create` command, which will provide useful debug messages. Each `-v` increases the verbosity from `INFO` to `DEBUG` to `TRACE`. I normally always use `DEBUG` because I hate seeing it just sit there when solving an environment.

```
conda create -v -v -v -n py34 python=3.4
```

I don't believe you needed to add `conda-forge`, the problem with your first command was that you didn't specify `python=3.4`, you did `version=3.4`. Try it without `conda-forge` and including `python=3.4` instead.

It also looks like your conda is broken, it's failing to resolve the environments which is likely not helping the situation. Try to fix that with

```
conda update --all
```

If you are still stuck with the same problem then review the conflicts with the following commands

```
conda info vc
conda info pip
conda info vs2010_runtime
```

I believe there is a chance that some of the packages in your base are incompatible with `3.4`. In this case you could try to install without any default packages

```
conda create --no-default-packages -n py34 python=3.4
```

If you are still running into issues, there is a chance there is something janky with your config files, so I would try doing a **[complete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53271833/8875915)** uninstall of anaconda on windows. And then attempt this again.

Comment: FInally at my PC again to try your fixes. Unfortunaly nothing helped,  I still get the same errors. Something seems really off with my installation of Anaconda. Even tried to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda. With the "no-default-packages" command i still get the same 'UnsatisfiableError'

Comment: I've updated my answer to try to help. Hopefully a full and total reinstall of Anaconda will help, or the debug messages will give some further light on this issue